# Does keychain data synced to iCloud back up

Tags: objective-c, iphone, backup, icloud, sskeychain

I have read so many blogs but still its not clear to me that whether iCloud backs up the **keychain** data which are stored programmatically using `SecItemAdd` or not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[iCloud Keychain](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204085) is a feature introduced with iOS 7.0.3 / OS X Mavericks 10.9.

In order to take advantage of this for data stored programmatically using `SecItemAdd`, you have to update the item with the key [kSecAttrSynchronizable](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/ksecattrsynchronizable).

This key is not added by default so items without it will **not** be backed up to iCloud.

Also, even with `kSecAttrSynchronizable` properly set, bear in mind that users might not have enabled the iCloud Keychain feature from their point of view, meaning that they wouldn't be synced either.

Comment: Thanx for your replay, Can we use kSecAttrSynchronizable attribute even to store encryption keys ? (which are generated through CommonCrypto APIs)